# Read the nested array in Azure Data Factory DataFlow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I have a complex json response returned from an API and I need to store some part of response into CSV file in Azure Storage Blob.

After some series of transformations in Data Flow, I finally able to filter the data that I need to store in CSV. Data looks as below:

```
"Rows": [
            [
                "record1",
                123,
                true,
                "test1"
            ],
            [
                "record2",
                456,
                false,
                "test2"
            ]
        ]
```

I was stuck at this point on how to process this kind of nested array. I have added the Derived column and tried with many expressions. But none works out.

I need the csv as below:

```
record1   123   true   test1
record2   456   false  test2
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve this will be helpful for me.

Response From ADX API for your reference:

```
[    
    {
        "FrameType": "DataTable",
        "TableId": 1,
        "TableKind": "PrimaryResult",
        "TableName": "PrimaryResult",
        "Columns": [
            {
                "ColumnName": "RecordID",
                "ColumnType": "string"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "RecordNumber",
                "ColumnType": "integer"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "IsValid",
                "ColumnType": "boolean"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "Remarks",
                "ColumnType": "string"
            }
        ],
        "Rows": [
            [
                "record1",
                123,
                true,
                "test1"
            ],
            [
                "record2",
                456,
                false,
                "test2"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: `I finally able to filter the data that I need to store in CSV. Data looks as below`? But what you have given is key value pair? Can you show the result of how your csv looks like?

Comment: Is the key-value pair given (rows) response returned by API?

Comment: Yes. Rows is a part of the response from API. In Rows array, we have multiple arrays where each sub array represent a record in table.

The API I am speaking about is the Azure Data Explorer REST API. It gives the table data in this kind of array format. Each sub array represents a record in the ADX table.

Comment: Can you provide an image of the whole API response?

Comment: I have updated the question with the API response. You can check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can pass the value of `Rows` from the API response to dataflow and apply transformations to get the desired results.
- Since I do not have access to your API, I have stored the response in a JSON file and accessed it using look up.

[image]

- Now, I have passed this value as a string to my dataflow parameter (named as str). I have taken a file with following data as source (any random file with 1 row and 1 column).

[image]

- Now, using the transformations as specified in the following dataflow JSON. I was able to achieve your requirement.

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "parameters{",
                "     str as string ('[[\"record1\",123,true,\"test1\"],[\"record2\",456,false,\"test2\"]]')",
                "}",
                "source(output(",
                "          id as integer",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(tp = toString(unfold(split($str, '],[')))) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 derive(tp = replace(replace(tp,'[[',''),']]','')) ~> derivedColumn2",
                "derivedColumn2 select(mapColumn(",
                "          tp",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['op.csv'],",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

- For Sink dataset, I have used the following configurations:

[image]

- The following is the resultant output file for reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Saideep. Your solution works for me. Most of the work is completed. At last I can get each record in single column with comma separated data. I will work on splitting this single column into multiple columns. Thank you once again.